# Train/test: why 80:20 split performed better than 90:10 split?

Tags: backtesting, algorithmic-trading, machine-learning, validation

Playing with Random Forest Classifier, I am wondering what could cause in a 80:20 split the test results to perform better than in a 90:10 split?

With 2000+ data points and:

- with 80:20 split, considering only the test set, the model generates 150 signals with around 55% accuracy
- with 90:10 split, considering only the test set, the model generates 77 signals with around 49% accuracy

From the images, it seems like the more the model 'sees', the worse it gets.

[image: 80:20]

[image: 90:10]

Comment: My *guess* is this shows a high sensitivity to the sample data chosen (not the amount of data). You might compare using the first 90% of the data versus using the last 90% of the data for example; same amount of data but different choice of time period. My guess is you get different results.

Comment: This could also be due to overfitting. Perhaps your tree has more depth in the 90% sample compared to the 80% sample--but the more depth explains noise that is not present in your test sample.